# Use Assets font that is not in Resources sub folder?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fonts, resources

Here's the dilemma:

I want to write a C# script for Unity3D that is planned to be released on the Assets Store and I want to include a custom font (of which I have full copyright) that is used by default in the script.

The docs tell that any assets that are loaded via `Resources.Load()` need to be in a Resources sub folder. AFAIK something like **Assets/Resources/Fonts/font.ttf** for example. But of course that's suboptimal for assets to be released on the Assets Store because your assets are in a top-level folder in Unity's Assets folder and most users wont want that and since you have all your other files together in a custom sub folder the font should be in that one as well.

Does somebody know of any other way to integrate a TTF font that is used by default in a script and which doesn't have to be in a Resources folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your understanding of the Resources folder is only partially correct.

The [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) function will work for any asset stored in ANY folder named **Resources** regardless of path

Example paths where it'll work

1. Assets/Resources/MyImage.png
2. Assets/MyAwesomePlugin/Resources/MyImage.png

You can load **MyImage.png** using Resources.Load regardless of which of the above paths you use.

The same applies for the **Plugins** and the **Editor** folders (if you were wondering)

Comment: heh, I saw your answer just after I hit Submit. Another /facedesk moment. :D

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I found out that you actually can have multiple Resources folders anywhere in custom subfolders and they are all combined internally by Unity when a game is built. This is cool and solves the issue!